# Problem installing QT on Vista

Tags: qt, windows-vista, qt4, qt-creator

I have downloaded QT SDK LGLP (Creator + libraries) 4.6 and I am having problems compiling projects. After install I have added C:\Qt\2010.02\qt;C:\Qt\2010.02\qt\bin to PATH and added QTDIR env varaible containing C:\Qt\2010.02\qt, the I run "configure -platform win32-g++" to compile it. Everything went good. 
I the tried to use QT Creator to create and compile a project.

The problem is everytime I try to compile I get the following error message:

> *No valid Qt version set. Set one in Tools/Options 
>   Error while building project GUITest
>   When executing build step 'QMake'
>   Canceled build.*

When I go to Tools/Options the manual version is set to v4.6.2, Location c:\qt\2010.02\qt\bin\qmake.exe. The auto detected version is set to  even though I have added the dirs in Path. Is there something I am doing wrong here? Has anyone encountered this problem in Vista.

I have been working on this for 2 days, change configurations, reinstalled etc...

Comment: Did you build Qt or just install a pre-built version? It's a long shot, but if you built it then if you also had an existing version of Qt lying around it might have used that `qmake` instead of building a  new one. This would mean that C:\qt\2010.02\qt\bin\qmake.exe might not actually exist?

Comment: To use Qt SDK for Windows you *do not* need to compile it yourself, and you don't need to modify your path (in Tools/Options/Qt4, set the "Default Qt Version" to the 'Manual' copy that came with the Qt4 SDK). I'd highly recommend against compiling it yourself when you're first getting started with it.

Answer (score 1):

> The QtDir value is compiled into the
>   qmake-binary. You can only change this
>   by recompiling qmake and passing on a
>   different value to qt-configure (I'm
>   not sure which setting or variable is
>   passed on to qmake) When using
>   precompiled, downloaded binaries,
>   you'll have to keep the QtDir at
>   c:\Qt\4.6.2

EDIT:
What I said was incorrect. The locations of qmake, moc,... are located in the file:

```
<Qt>/4.x.x/.qmake.cache
```

Comment: I have set QTDIR to c:\Qt\4.6.2 and re-configured...
The problem isn't solved. Has anyone installed QT SDK on Vista?

Comment: Get anyone please tell me the steps necessary to install QT SDK package (Creator and libs) on Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling/reinstalling qt creator

But i highly suspect you didnt compile qt properly as this problem seems really odd. I had alot of problems compiling so i know myself from the past mistakes.

Make sure you carefully reread install instructions for your environment, also if you have visual studio you need to follow procedure to install it in compliance with it. Same if you use another c compiler

If nothing goes right, the easiest way to install qt imo is directy from their git hub, chec installin qt from git, on their git site there is wiki that explains how to do it

its really easy and after that all you need to do is add the qt to creator

Answer (score -1):

Hey, it QT emulators have lot of problems in vista, i have tried several times,it didnt work for me.. it works well with windows XP. though ill tell you in brief what you need to do
1)install latest perl
2)install carbide c++ editor
3)install Qt SDK
4)install s60 or N97 emulators

make sure that except perl all the items which are mentioned above will be in same drive,and also 
make sure that folder names which you give while installation should not have spaces at all..

i.e suppose if you are going to place any of the above items in a folder whose name is having spaces it will not work.

if you have any doubts feel free to ask.

Comment: The problems I am having are not with the emulators but with the Creator. I just want to build a simple GUI application for Windows but cannot compile it. Do I need to install perl and carbide for this?

Comment: actually i had told the above steps for symbian OS. any way you need perl i guess, and carbide is for symbian i dont no will it go for desktop or not try once else you can install another application called "QT creator" for that..

Comment: You do not need Perl or Carbide to create desktop applications. All you need is to download 'Qt SDK for Windows' from qt.nokia.com, and install that, then double check in Qt Creator in Tools -> Options -> Qt4 that at least one Qt installation is found, and that the "Default Qt Version" is set to that. No perl, no carbide, no compiling the Qt source, no black magic.

Comment: @kitsune:
just check the tittle of the post.."Problem installing QT on Vista"
i just thought it would be for Qt symbian and answered..